# jQuery $.ajax success not firing from JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

My code makes an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/EmailUserKeys",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

It calls an action in my controller which returns some JSON:

```
public JsonResult EmailUserKeys(string UserId)
{
    ...
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

My problem is that the ajax error function is called and not the ajax success function.

Why?

PS. If my action returns "return null;", the ajax success function is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must allow GET which is disabled by default when returning JSON results:

```
public JsonResult EmailUserKeys(string UserId)
{
    ...
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or use a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/EmailUserKeys",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { userId: 'some user id' },
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Also never hardcode the url to your controller action as you did. Always use url helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
url: "@Url.Action("EmailUserKeys", "Controller")",
```

And here's a piece of advice: use a javascript debugging tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you are doing any web development. Among with other useful things it allows you to inspect AJAX requests. If you had used it you would have seen the response sent from the server which would have looked like this:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

And you wouldn't need to come to StackOverflow and ask this question as you would have already known the answer.

Comment: Thank-you Darin. I did not know that FireBug allowed me to inspect AJAX requests. I do already have it installed and shall use it next time I have problems with AJAX.

Comment: @Robert, no, not only when you have problems with AJAX. Use it all the time when you have problems with javascript. FireBug does many more things than AJAX inspection.

Answer (score 5):

You should edit your code to this:

```
public JsonResult EmailUserKeys(string UserId)
{
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

See the official documentation for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior.aspx

The reason for disabling this by default is because of JSON hijacking. More information about this can be found here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for your answer also. It too shows how to solve my problem. @Darin Dimitrov also mentions that Firebug allows you to see AJAX requests which I think will be helpful for other users.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out!